# Get monthly report in sql

Tags: sql

I got in my data base colums logs, data, type
How to get logs from year from now with month distinction
f.ex:
row

```
logs = 'error...'
data = 2012-11-05 11:24:08
type = 1
```

....
And I want get them in that view

```
month     logs-count   type
January     100         1
January     100         2
February    160         1
February    120         2
 ....
```

Comment: Is there any year field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysql:

```
select monthname(data) as month, count(*) as logs-count, type
  from table
  group by month, type
```

You need to group by both date and type to get multiple rows per month.

Answer (score 0):

try this,If these columns are in same table

```
select monthname(data) as month,count(logs)as logs-count,type from table
 group by month
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
select datename(month, data) as month count(logs)as logscount, type from table
```